# I have an obscure border on my input in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I want to make the input element completely devoid of border, I removed the border, made its length 0, removed the outline, but still Firefox shows a border of 2px on each side. Why can this happen? I use Firefox Develop Edition.

Here are screenshots describing the situation:

The first screenshot shows the Firefox browser: 
[image: The first screenshot shows the Firefox browser]

Inspector in Firefox: 
[image: Shown is the inspector in Firefox]

The same element in Chrome: 
[image: The same element in Chrome]

This is code on the screenshots applied to .quest__form-default

```css
.quest__form-default {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px;
      width: 1px;
      height: 1px;
      clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
      overflow: hidden;
      border: 0;
      outline: 0;
      border-width: 0px;
    }

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) IMAGES OF CODE ARE NOT AN ACCEPTABLE SUBSTITUTE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using these `appearance` properties on the checkbox:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

Otherwise, your best bet is to just match the border color to the background color of the parent element (not the best way)